# Hover not working for the whole block

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to create a hover effect for the whole anchor element but it's not working, as soon as the mouse is out of the text the drop down menu disappears:

[Here](http://amaechiperformance.tangent-design.com/) is the test site.

Css:

```
.menu{}
.menu li{float:left;margin-right:24px;list-style-type:none;height:46px;}
.menu li a{width:100%;text-transform: uppercase;color:#39444A;text-decoration:none;font-weight: bold;font-size:18px;display:block;height:46px;}
.menu li a:hover{border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 2px;border-bottom-color: #E87D05;color:#E87D05;height:46px;display:block;}
ul.sub_navigation , .sub_navigation
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image: url('/images/menu-bg-png.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 28px;

 }
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS ( add ):

```
.menu li a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: but the underline effect of mouse hover doesnt work correctly

Comment: @MrA I don't know how it is supposed to work ( You wrote the code for that, not me ) and it is kinda unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your case is because the div `#slider-container` is overlaping the `#header` div. I see that the `#slider-container` is absolute.

1. In this case you can add extra 20 - 30px on the `TOP` property and get rid of the padding-top.
2. The other thing to do is just to add `position:relative` and `z-index:10` (for example) on the `#header` div

Answer (score 0):

the anchor elements have the size of the text and nothing else.
The space between link and link is the right margin of the li.

remove

```
li {margin_right: 40px}
```

and set

```
a {padding_right: 40px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menu > li:hover .sub_navigation {
    display: block;
}
```